# Can I create shopify theme extension app, without app?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I have a simple javascript widget rendering the content based on API key from the settings. (I store API keys on my infrastructure)

I am trying to create a Shopify app, to allow merchants to use my widget.

Using the widget is very simple, all you need to do is add one line of javascript.

I would store the api key setting in metafields then.

What would be the best way to approach it? I have seen, tutorials like this one

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYz_XMY7jEU&t=301s

where the developer creates the Theme app extension, without creating app itself. Is it possible?

You could store the API key in the metadata then.

When I try to run the command

```
command `extension create
```

shopify extension generate
I have the result "command `extension create` not found. did you mean `version`?"

Do I need to create an app to publish the theme extension?

I want to avoid creating an app, because from what I have seen it requires storing application on an external server, and I would like to create something lighter.

Or maybe there is a different way to approach it?

II am using osx, Ruby 2.7.5, Shopify CLI 3.45.4
`command extension create`
did not create an extension
I was able to do it only from the Shopify app

Answer (score 2):

You need an App to contain a theme App extension. When the merchant installs you App, even if all it delivers is a JS widget, they are still installing an App. If you embed a code in a metafield for your JS widget, be aware that that code becomes public knowledge and is not private. You cannot hide codes in the front-end.